# How to get the input step's info in the sub transition

Tags: pentaho, kettle

[image]

Hello, everyone!
I had create a kettle trans like the picture.
Now,in the "concat value" step,  I want to use its  the "A, B" step metainfo,but I not know how to get it.Could you help me.
I can get the mapping input step info,but I not know how to get its privous step
.I want to get the "A,B" step info.
Tks!
"concat value"step code:

```
//Script here

function format() {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, function (m, i) {
        return args[i * 1 - 1];
    });
}
function getArr() {
    var fs = getVariable('fields', '');
    var arr = fs.split(',');
    var varr = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < getInputRowMeta().size(); i++) { //loop through the actual row

            // Grab the metadata for this value
            //
            var valueMeta = getInputRowMeta().getValueMeta(i);

            //using the IDs instead of "String" would make it faster, see API for the IDs
            //
            if (valueMeta.getName().equals(arr[j])) { //only for String types
                varr.push(row[i]);
                break;
            }

        }

    }
    return varr;

}
function getwww() {
    var trans = _step_.getTrans();
    if (trans == null) {
        return 'err';
    }
    var transmeta = trans.getTransMeta();
    if (transmeta == null) {
        return 'err';
    }
    var minput = trans.findMappingInput();
    if (minput == null) {
        return 'err';
    }
    var arrs = transmeta.getPrevStepNames(minput[0].getStepMeta());
    var arr2 = [];
    var rowset = minput[0].getInputRowSets()
        for (var i = 0; i < rowset.length; i++) {
            arr2.push(rowset[i].getName());
        }

        return arr2.join('/');
}
var result = format.apply(getVariable('format', ''), getArr());
var pname = getwww();
```

Comment: Why exaclty do you need a Sub-transformation for that ? Depending on what is it you're trying to achieve it can be done using just steps. Remenber that performance wise, using a JavaScript step will slow down your transformation.

Comment: I want to create a sub-trans which can output its privious step name and then I can know the data from which step.For example, a merge step have multiple inputs,I can insert the subtrans between input step and merge step,so that I can know every row come from which step.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a Sub-transformation, but you could use a Modified Java Script Value using this:

```
var last_step = _step_.getInputRowSets();
```

This will return the name of the previous step followed by the name of the current step(the Modified Java Script Value), you can extract this value with a few String cleaning / Split steps.

By using this with a Dummy step before it, it outputs this String:

[Dummy (do nothing) 2.0 - Modified Java Script Value.0]

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve the problem.
//Script here

```
function getSubPreStepName() {
    var trans = _step_.getTrans();
    if (trans == null) {
        return 'err';
    }
    var transpar = trans.getParentTrans();
    if (transpar == null) {
        return 'err';
    }
    var transmeta = trans.getTransMeta();
    if (transmeta == null) {
        return 'err';
    }
    var ptransmeta = transpar.getTransMeta();
    var arrs = trans.toString().split("\\.");
    var subname = arrs[arrs.length - 2].replace('\[', '').replace('\]', '');
    var topstep = ptransmeta.findStep(subname)
        return ptransmeta.getPrevStepNames(topstep)[0];
}
var pname = getSubPreStepName();
```